# Javascript object and parameters reference from the HTML

Tags: javascript, object

I have this idea of mine that I want to implement by using function parameters and objects, but the its not working as expected.

First HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripting.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div >
            <form id='radio'>
                <input type="radio" name="choice" onClick="text(this.value)" value="list">
                <input type="radio" name="choice" onClick="text(this.value)" value="box"></form>
            <h1 id="title">" "</h1>
            <p id="description"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is quite straight forward, I will use the value of the radio button as a parameter for my javascript text() function.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var choices = document.getElementsByName('choice');
var list = { a : 1 , b : 'Hi' };
var box = { a : 2, b : 'Hello'};


function text(choice) {

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i += 1)
    {
        if(choices[i].checked)
        {
            document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = choice["a"];
            document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = choice["b"];
        }
    }

}
```

I have created two objects with same name as the radio button from the HTML code. Next, in my function made a for loop to check which radio button is clicked. Based on the formula, the Head and Paragraph tags should display object contents in their respective tags. When I just input the parameter as a plain value, it prints out the value of the radio button. However, I am using the parameter as a reference to object variable. Example:

```
function parameter choice = "list";
document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = choice["a"];
```

Instead of getting the value displayed. I get "undefined" as a result.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: choice is a string, so just use `... = choice;`

Comment: Already tried that. Same result

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to approach this.  If you keep the current variables and now that they will be global (in the window object), then use this:

```
var list = { a : 1 , b : 'Hi' };
var box = { a : 2, b : 'Hello'};
var choice = 'list';

console.log(window[choice]);
```

Notice we put choice in bracket because list and box are properties of window.

Because choice equals 'list', therefore, window[choice], window['list'], and window.list all refer to the same object named list.

Another approach is to place list and box in an object:

```
var types = {
  list: { a : 1 , b : 'Hi' },
  box: { a : 2, b : 'Hello' }
};

var choice = 'list';

console.log(types[choice]);
```

I prefer this method over putting everything in the global/window object.

Comment: Keep in mind that my result should be displayed on the HTML5 site, not in a console.
Also, the choice parameter is not an existing variable, its a reference to a value from a HTML5 function text(this.value)...In the example I put in my original post, I meant that this.value = 'list' as parameter for function text(choice); and in the javascript -choice- will represent the value 'list' in the entire function. I tried your option types[choice] but it throws: [ object Object ] as a result.

Comment: I was just showing you how to get an object using a variable, like window[choice].  Since list and box are objects, you need to reference it like window[choice].a or window[choice].b.  I thought I would let you come up with the actual code, but let us know if you need more help to get the actual result.